# XCode 14.0.1 error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (React Native project)

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I'm trying to run my React Native project on XCode so that I can get it to run on my iOS device, everything works perfectly fine in VS Code and the Simulator software, but XCode simply refuses to build the project, throwing the error:

```
error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

This error occurs even when I try running an untouched new project (the example `init` project from react-native).

I tried these solutions:

- deintegrating and reinstalling pods
- running this command: `npx react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle`
- Locking and unlocking the "login" keychain, I wasn't able to lock the keychain in the first place, the option is greyed out. What could cause that?
- run `pod install` in the ios directory

I use:

- XCode 14.0.1
- M1 Macbook Air
- MacOS Big Sur 12.6
- React Native 9.1.3 (at least that's what `npx react-native -v` says, but node modules -> react-native -> package.json in my project says it's 0.70.1)

If there are any more details you need please let me know, thanks.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the build's report in the report navigator
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMolH.png)

Comment: That's not the real error message - can you look for errors above that line in the build logs? Have you run `pod install`?

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot of the build log ( I think that's what it is), and I just tried running pod install in the ios directory, did nothing

Comment: The error says you need nvm and node. Do you have them installed? Also, what does "did nothing" mean?

Comment: I use chruby as my ruby version manager and I read that I need only one of them, I guess I have node too, just to be on the safe side how do I check if it's installed?
"did nothing" means that I got the same error. What was supposed to be installed when I ran it?

Comment: not RVM, NVM.  Node Version Manager.  `brew install nvm && nvm install node`

Comment: Have you tried running npx react-native run-ios, or launching directly from xcode?